# Power Pivot "dynamic" joins

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot

I have a situation where I kind of need a many-to-many join - which I know isn't possible.
I have one fact table and two dimension tables.
The fact table contains account numbers (as in GL accounts) and amounts. Plus a date field, so the account numbers are not unique.
The first dimension table has just one column listing the reports that can be created by combining the accounts in different ways.
The second dimension table could be called a "roll-up" table. It has 3 columns: report, account, and a line item description field.  The latter defines which line on the respective report that the account should be mapped to.

So I want to have a pivot table that has the line item description in the row area and the amount in the values area. With a mechanism for the user to specify which report they want to view.  But the join on the account field between the roll-up table and the fact table is many-to-many.  If the roll-up table were somehow filtered based on the specific report that the user has selected, THEN it would become one-to-many.  Hence the "dynamic" joins in my title.

I've been trying to come up with a connecting table of some kind, but without any luck so far.  If anybody has any suggestions/pointers, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it using a DAX formula that calculates the field to be placed in the Values area.  It uses FILTER and CROSSJOIN combinations to effect the dynamic joins.  Note that in order to use a CROSSJOIN I added prefix letters to a couple of the field names (to make them unique).  Also, I made it that the Report table (the first dimension table I described) has only one row - containing the report that the user wishes to view.

The DAX formula is as follows:

```
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        CROSSJOIN (
            fBalances,
            FILTER (
                CROSSJOIN (
                    dRollUp,
                    dReport
                ), dRollup[Report] = dReport[uReport]
            )
        ), fBalances[fAccount] = dRollUp[Account]
    ), fBalances[Amount]
)
```

Subsequent update: I moved it into Power BI where I added a parameter (called myReport) for the user to specify the report.  Consequently I deleted the dReport table.

So the Power BI DAX formula becomes:

```
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        CROSSJOIN (
            fBalances,
            FILTER (
                CROSSJOIN (
                    dRollUp,
                    myReport
                ), dRollup[Report] = FIRSTNONBLANK ( myReport[myReport], TRUE() )
            )
        ), fBalances[fAccount] = dRollUp[Account]
    ), fBalances[Amount]
)
```